# read JsonObject Java

Tags: java, json

I get a JsonObject from another server like this:

```
{"data": {
 "key": "Cooking.Oven.Program.HeatingMode.HotAir",
    "options": [
      {
        "key": "Cooking.Oven.Option.SetpointTemperature",
        "value": 230,
        "unit": "°C"
      },
      {
        "key": "BSH.Common.Option.Duration",
        "value": 1200,
        "unit": "seconds"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My problem is now. How can I separate this JsonObject in smaller parts.
If this would be a normal object with one key value pair, I would transfere it to a map. But here the line

```
Map<String, String> map = toMap(this.json);

 private Map<String, String> toMap(JsonObject json) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    }.getType());
 }
```

throws an error

```
Exception occurred while informing handler: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAYcom.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

What is the easiest solution to get all the entries to a map?
Do you have any hints or cues for me?

Comment: You haven't posted your `toMap` code but the error message seems pretty self-explanative.

Comment: your problem is you are trying to map to Strings, but the data in your json are not Strings, but composite objects

Comment: You could try `Map<String, Object>` instead.

Comment: Thank you! The combination of Map<String, Object> and the function .toString() solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    //... get JSON string
    String jsonResponse = yourJsonResponseString;

    // parse JSON
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (jsonResponse);
    JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
    String key = data.getString("key");
    JSONArray options = data.getJSONArray("options");
    for(i=0; i<options.length(); i++){
      JSONObject optionsObject = options.getJSONObject(i);
      String key = optionsObject.getString("key");
      int value = optionsObject.getInt("value");
      String unit = optionsObject.getString("unit");
      // ... put these values into some object or store it somehow..
    }
```

So, *first* you have to get values from JSON into String, int etc. *Then* you can add those values into your custom data structure.
I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it later.

Comment: I solved the problem in another way. See the comments above.